# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target (react-mock-store)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Getting the following error and I don't understand because it seems like I am matching the signature

> [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
>   const mockStore: (state?: {
>       todo: string[]; } | undefined) => IStore<{
>       todo: string[]; }>

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'

type MyStore = {
    todo: string[];
}

const mockStore = configureMockStore<MyStore>([]);

let storeVar : MyStore = {todo: ['one','two']};
const store = mockStore<MyStore>(storeVar);
```

The typedef for [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store) is coming from [DefinitivelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped):

```
// Type definitions for Redux Mock Store v0.0.6
// Project: https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store
// Definitions by: Marian Palkus <https://github.com/MarianPalkus>, Cap3 <http://www.cap3.de>
// Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

///<reference types="redux" />

declare module 'redux-mock-store' {
    import * as Redux from 'redux'

    function createMockStore<T>(middlewares?: Redux.Middleware[]): mockStore<T>;

    export type mockStore<T> = (state?: T) => IStore<T>;

    export interface IStore<T> {
        dispatch(action: any): any;
        getState(): T;
        getActions(): any[];
        clearActions(): void;
        subscribe(listener: Function): Function;
    }

    export default createMockStore
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the type parameter when you call `mockStore`. `createMockStore` already returns a `mockStore` with the type filled:

```
const store = mockStore(storeVar);
```